# Why does combo-box return the wrong value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, combobox

When I run my program and get it to give me the value (Yes, I do have the items in the drop down list selected) in the combo-box all I get is this,

> System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox+ObjectCollection

This is the code I am using

```
 Dim name As String
        name = cmbworld.Text
        MsgBox(name)
```

Any ideas?

P.S. The code I used to insert the values is

```
cmbworld.Items.Clear()

     If File.Exists(root + "\setting\world.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\setting\world.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbworld.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    Else
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you put values into the combobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code would reproduce the problem:

```
    Dim name As String
    name = cmbworld.Items.ToString()
    MsgBox(name)
```

You have some other code somewhere that is assigning the value of the Text property incorrectly.  You need to index the Items collection.  For example:

```
    cmbworld.Text = cmbWorld.Items(0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused... How do I get the value out of the combobox. I assigned the items in the drop down list with the code above. Is it an error in that code? And where am i mean to place the "cmbworld.Text = cmbWorld.Items(0)"

Comment: No, the code you posted is fine.  I had to work from the assumption that you have other code in your program that assigned the Text property wrong.  I don't know if you do, it was a guess.  The only thing that made sense.  Unmark the answer if it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 3):

The code you are posting can't be what is not working in your code.

Taking your example, I get a clean message with a line of data from my text file.

The only way I get your message is when I do the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(cmbworld.Items.ToString)
```

I would put a stop debugger on that MsgBox line and check the values.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property, use SelectedText.

cmbworld.SelectedText